# jquery: how to decode the stringized utf-8 character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

My python server uses json.dumps() to dump the json object into the string, but it also converts the binary utf-8 code which is not ascii, into the stringized thing, like "\u4e2d". So what my client see is this string, is there any api to convert "\u4e2d" back to utf-8 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery you can use [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to decode a JSON-formatted object. That includes decoding encoded characters. Using `dataType: 'json'` with [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (or [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)) or using [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) will do that for you if you are trying to make AJAX requests.